# How to take values from array and add it as class to html items

Tags: javascript, arrays

Problem : 
I have list in HTML, 5 `li > a`  inside `u`l and I created array in JS such as :

```
var list= [
{
    date: "02.2013",
    name: "First",
    icon: "fa fa-heart"
},
{
    date: "05.2014",
    name: "Second",
    icon: "fa fa-flask"
},
{
    date: "03.2012",
    name: "Third",
    icon: "fa fa-gavel"
},
{
    date: "06.2015",
    name: "Fourth",
    icon: "fa fa-graduation-cap"
},
{
    date: "08.2017",
    name: "Fifth",
    icon: "fa fa-trophy"
}];
```

and i want to add "ICON" content as classes to a. 
Result should be sth like that :

```
                 <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"  class="fa fa-heart"  aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"  class="fa fa-flask" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"   class="fa fa-gavel" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"  class="fa fa-graduation-cap" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"  class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
```

I can display in console every "ICON" in table, same with "a" but I have no idea what should be next step

How can I take these "classes" from array and put it inside links?

for / foreach  ??

I ask for hints, not for solutions - thanks for every comment bros

Comment: Do you truly want to use javascript as the tag show? or are you open to JQuery? It is much less code jquery

Comment: You can use .classList (an array) or className (a string) to add classes to elements using JS

Answer (score 1):

A JS solution:

```
var html_content = "<ul>";
for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++){
    html_content += '<li><a href="#"  class="'+list[i]['icon']+'"  aria-hidden="true"></a>';
}
html_content+= "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Get a collection of the links, loop over them, and add the corresponding classes from the array.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("li > a");
var len = Math.min(links.length, list.length);
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    links[i].className = list[i].icon;
}
```